# Rails 4 - force browser to execute javascript response instead of displaying text

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller, render

I have a Rails 4 application where I need to force the controller to send a js response to all requests, html or js.  For some reason, the browser is displaying the response as text instead of executing the code when the controller receives an html request (for example, when the user makes a request by typing in the url).

**Controller:**

```
def action
  render :template => 'sessions/home.js.erb', :content_type => "text/javascript"
end
```

**sessions/home.js.erb:**

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){
  alert("got here");
});
```

Instead of binding #button, the browser simply displays the code from home.js.erb as text.

I've tried the following options in the controller but the results are the same - the browser just presents the text vs executing the code:

```
render js: "alert('got here')";
```

or

```
render :format => :js, :template => 'sessions/home.js.erb'
```

or

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html {render :template => 'sessions/home.js.erb', :content_type => 'text/javascript'}
end
```

or

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html {render :template => 'sessions/home.js.erb', :content_type => 'application/javascript'}
end
```

Can somebody help me figure out what I need to do in order to get the browser to execute the javascript?

Comment: i am facing the same issue - have you figured out a solution for this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Rails can deliver you [code](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-vanilla-javascript), but it's up to you to ensure that the code is loaded and executed on the clientside, otherwise it really is just text.

Jquery has a few handy helpers just for this thing

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  dataType: "script"
});
```

This will Load and Execute a Javascript file.  Or you can use

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( data ); // Data returned
  console.log( textStatus ); // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Both examples copied from the Jquery api docs.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
and
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: I understand the use of .ajax and .getScript; however, in my case, I'm not using jquery to send the request.  Rather, the request is directly coming from the user typing in the url into browser.  Thus, it's an html request going to the server but I need to have the browser execute the javascript response instead of simply displaying the javascript code as text.  Based on your answer, it sounds seems like the browser will only execute a javascript response when a javascript request (i.e. ajax) is made to the server.  Is that accurate?

Comment: If you are on a page, and you wish to load javascript that interacts with that page (ie, binding #button to an event).  Then there is literally no other way to do that then to 1) send the code with the page itself, or 2) use Ajax to grab the snippit of code and load it.  To make a separate HTTP request will cause your browser to trash the current html page and load whatever the url returns (which in your case is text that is simply displayed).

Comment: My binding #button example may have not been the best example to use.  In reality, my code is actually using the .html() method as I want to disregard the current page and load whatever the url returns.  The only issue is that I want to browser to execute .html() rather than display the code.  Hope that clarifies this topic and thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Overwrite the response content type. Read more about the response object here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-response-object

**Try out this:**

```
def action
  response.content_type = Mime[:js]
  render js: "alert('got here');"
end
```

**Or for all actions:**

```
before_filter :force_js

def force_js
  response.content_type = Mime[:js]
end
```

**Or with respond_to:**

```
def action
  respond_to do |format|
    format.any(:html, :js) { render js: "alert('got here');" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Can anyone verify this?

Comment: It doesn't work. It just spits out the JS file as plaintext.

Comment: No longer valid with current Rails due to forgery protection